# Selenium-webdriver dropdownlist not work php

Tags: php, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I want to choose one first drop-down list, then the second, but I can not even cope with the first
Please explain why I get the error

```
<?php
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";
$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");                            
$webdriver->get("http://namami.org/PKstate.aspx");
//$element = $webdriver->findElement('css selector', 'select[id="DdlState"] option[value="Assam"]');
$element = $webdriver->findElement("css selector", 'select[id="DdlState"] option[value="Assam"]')->click();
//$element=$webdriver->findElement(By.cssSelector("#DdlState")).click();
//$element->‌​click();
$webdriver->close();
?>
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method WebDriver::findElement() in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\1.php on line 7

I could not find an answer. Use XAMPP.
I would be grateful for your help.
Regards Anton

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to delay the click.

The item that you're attempting to grab with Selenium is generated by Javascript, and I think what's happening is that the Selenium is trying to find something that isn't quite rendered yet.

Try calling 
`sleep(1);` to delay the Selenium action and see if that works:

```
<?php
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";
$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");                            
$webdriver->get("http://namami.org/PKstate.aspx");
sleep(1); // allow the javascript some time to load
//$element = $webdriver->findElement('css selector', 'select[id="DdlState"] option[value="Assam"]');
//$element = $webdriver->findElement("css selector", 'select[id="DdlState"] option[value="Assam"]')->click();
////$element=$webdriver->findElement(By.cssSelector("#DdlState")).click();
////$element->‌​click();
//$webdriver->close();
//?>
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not solve the problem, I do not see page

Comment: tell me how to do this please

Comment: noticed that the old xampp webdriver - replaced here https://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/
But now new Notice, even by their example

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\php\pear\phpwebdriver\WebDriver.php on line 58

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\php\pear\phpwebdriver\WebDriver.php on line 60
and the result is a blank page, it should be

https://github.com/daluu/php-webdriver-bindings/blob/master/example.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";    
    $webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");    
    $webdriver->connect("firefox");
    $webdriver->get("http://namami.org/PKstate.aspx");    
    sleep(1); // allow the javascript some time to load    
    $element = $webdriver->findElement('id', 'DdlState');    
    $select = new Select($element);    
    $select->selectByValue("Assam");
    //?>
```